# Kotlin Mockito calls mocked method

Tags: kotlin, mockito-kotlin

I've been away from mockito for awhile, so this is probably a newbie issue.

```
package somepackage

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.kotlin.doNothing
import org.mockito.kotlin.mock
import org.mockito.kotlin.whenever

var called = false

open class SUT {
    fun doWork(type: String) {
        println("Doing $type work")
        called = true
    }
}

class MockTest {

    @Test
    fun `test doNothing`() {
        val sut: SUT = mock()
        doNothing().whenever(sut).doWork("busy")

        sut.doWork("busy")
        assert(!called)
    }
}
```

The test fails as `doWork()` was called.  Twice.   If I replace "busy" with `any()` in the mock, it fails with a NPE.

I'm expecting it to not call the actual method and do, well, nothing.   Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Easy solve:   Just add an open to the function:

**open** fun doWork(type: String) {